# problem with update of libreoffice

Tags: 12.04, updates, 64-bit, libreoffice

This is a problem:

```
~$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:3.5.7) but 1:3.5.4-0ubuntu1.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Than I used what is said output below:

```
~$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bind9utils libmcrypt4
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
Suggested packages:
  libreoffice-style-hicontrast libreoffice-style-crystal
  libreoffice-style-oxygen
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libreoffice-common
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
14 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/20.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,048 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
(Reading database ... 428585 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libreoffice-common 1:3.5.4-0ubuntu1.1 (using .../libreoffice-common_1%3a3.5.7-0ubuntu4_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libreoffice-common ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a3.5.7-0ubuntu4_all.deb (--unpack):
 corrupted filesystem tarfile - corrupted package archive
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
rmdir: failed to remove `/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove `/var/lib/libreoffice/share/': Directory not empty
rmdir: failed to remove `/var/lib/libreoffice/program/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove `/var/lib/libreoffice': Directory not empty
rmdir: failed to remove `/var/lib/libreoffice': Directory not empty
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a3.5.7-0ubuntu4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Than i looked up for error message found this [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1642173) 
using it give next output

```
~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-core:
 libreoffice-core depends on libreoffice-common (>> 1:3.5.7); however:
  Version of libreoffice-common on system is 1:3.5.4-0ubuntu1.1.
dpkg: error processing libreoffice-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-style-human:
 libreoffice-style-human depends on libreoffice-core; however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libreoffice-style-human (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-math:
 libreoffice-math depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:3.5.7-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libreoffice-math (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-impress:
 libreoffice-impress depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:3.5.7-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libreoffice-impress (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-style-tango:
 libreoffice-style-tango depends on libreoffice-core; however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libreoffice-style-tango (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-writer:
 libreoffice-writer depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:3.5.7-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libreoffice-writer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-base-core:
 libreoffice-base-core depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:3.5.7-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libreoffice-base-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-gnome:
 libreoffice-gnome depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:3.5.7-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libreoffice-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-emailmerge:
 libreoffice-emailmerge depends on libreoffice-core; however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libreoffice-emailmerge (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-gtk:
 libreoffice-gtk depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:3.5.7-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libreoffice-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-uno:
 python-uno depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:3.5.7-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python-uno (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-draw:
 libreoffice-draw depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:3.5.7-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libreoffice-draw (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-help-en-us:
 libreoffice-help-en-us depends on libreoffice-writer | language-support-translations-en; however:
  Package libreoffice-writer is not configured yet.
  Package language-support-translations-en is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libreoffice-help-en-us (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-calc:
 libreoffice-calc depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:3.5.7-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-calc depends on libreoffice-base-core (= 1:3.5.7-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package libreoffice-base-core is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libreoffice-calc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libreoffice-core
 libreoffice-style-human
 libreoffice-math
 libreoffice-impress
 libreoffice-style-tango
 libreoffice-writer
 libreoffice-base-core
 libreoffice-gnome
 libreoffice-emailmerge
 libreoffice-gtk
 python-uno
 libreoffice-draw
 libreoffice-help-en-us
 libreoffice-calc
```

If anyone has fixed the problem, tell me what to do

Comment: Are you using the Libreoffice PPA? I had problems with it on 12.10 and removed the PPA. Problem solved.

Comment: Looks like you need to remove the old version first and then install the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These is what i have done

- Deleted everything in folder  /var/cache/apt/
- Turnd off ppa

and update now works
Thanks to all who commented