# Errors were encountered processing libreoffice-common

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice, dependencies, synaptic

I have tried using "sudo apt-get -f install" and I have also tried "sudo apt-get install -f" to fix the dependencies with no luck. This is also preventing me from installing Synaptic to remove libreoffice and fix the problems. I have both Openoffice and Libreoffice

```
miguel@Miguel:~$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
libreoffice-common
Suggested packages:
libreoffice-style-crystal libreoffice-style-hicontrast
libreoffice-style-oxygen libreoffice-style-sifr
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libreoffice-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/20.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 79.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 263460 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a4.4.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~trusty1_all.deb   ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:4.4.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~trusty1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-   common_1%3a4.4.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~trusty1_all.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice-  debian-menus 4.1-9764
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/share/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/program/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice’: No such file or directory
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.10.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.4.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~trusty1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact error message you are getting..

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this is A Confirmed Bug

If you are running antivirus... like sophos, you need to disable on demand scanner and then update your system and then re enable your on demand scanner.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1454668

Answer (score 0):

The key to the problem is near the top of the error messages:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.4.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~trusty1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice-debian-menus 4.1-9764
```

Let's abstract that error message a bit to make it more readable:

```
dpkg: error processing archive PACKAGE_NAME_A.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite 'FILE', which is also in PACKAGE_B
```

Explanation: With only a few exceptions, each file can be provided by only one package. When two packages provide the same file, the two packages *conflict*, which causes the error message.

That way you resolve the error is to uninstall either PACKAGE_A (libreoffice-common) or PACKAGE_B (openoffice-debian-menus).

Do note that this problem was not a bug - a human caused it by mixing incompatible packages from PPAs and Debian. Users who stick with the Ubuntu repositories (or Snaps) won't have this problem.

Answer (score -1):

1. gksudo nautilus
2. Deleted everything with in folder /var/cache/apt/
3. Turn the ppa of for Libreoffice
4. run sudo apt-get -f install

This worked for me and was originally posted on [problem with update of libreoffice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258738/problem-with-update-of-libreoffice), I just added a few things to clarify a bit.